# How to add Single sign-on support for bots to existing application?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

Currently we have an application in production that allows for Single sign-on in tabs, we followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso and this works well.

For this to work an *Application ID URI* is set, like so: `api://www.domainusedintab.com/378271d1-b8e4-4f01-a9bb-e724dbec43c8`, where `378271d1-b8e4-4f01-a9bb-e724dbec43c8` is some application ID.

We now want to add Single sign-on support for bots, like described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots. To make this work a change is needed to the *Application ID URI*, `api://botid-5d417275-b104-462e-9998-2b2b0ec4244f`, where `5d417275-b104-462e-9998-2b2b0ec4244f` is the ID of the bot service.

The problem is that it's not clear on how to combines these two into a single *Application ID URI*, based on the previous documentation pages it seems it's one way or the other.

We tried to just tack on `/botid-5d417275-b104-462e-9998-2b2b0ec4244f` after our current *Application ID URI*, to make `api://www.domainusedintab.com/378271d1-b8e4-4f01-a9bb-e724dbec43c8/botid-5d417275-b104-462e-9998-2b2b0ec4244f`. This seems to work fine... But it also seems like a bit of a hack that might break at any time.

Are there any resources on how to properly solve this?

Comment: Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/teams-sso/csharp_dotnetcore)?

Comment: We got the functionality of Single sign-on for bots working in our development environment, the question is specific about the Application ID URI with multiple IDs; can we add the `botid-` part to our existing Application ID URI, or is there another way to do this. It's not documented and we don't want to be surprised if it turns out there is a right way to do it.

Comment: You can add the bot id to and existing application.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: We're moving forward with the added `botid-` for the updated manifest, it has not yet entered the review stage. Will know more at a later stage.

Comment: When you add Application Id URI you need to add web application info in your manifest - please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots#update-your-teams-application-manifest-for-your-bot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is possible to provide multiple *Application ID URIs* for an App registration. This is not available through the *Expose an API* interface, you need to change it directly in the manifest. The `identifierUris` field holds the *Application ID URIs* — the current one from the *Expose an API* interface should be the only item here.

Answer (score 0):

We can add the existing bots to the existing application to work on SSO. We need to add the web applcation info in the manifest to view the changes in the application. For more information please check [Single sign-on (SSO) support for bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots#update-your-teams-application-manifest-for-your-bot)